# Shell with parameters order of entry is the issue

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, parameter

```
     while (("$#"))
do
opt="$1";
    shift;
        case "$opt" in
           "-c" | "--create") create_flag=1 ;;
           "-up" | "--update") update_flag=1 ;;
           "-q" | "--query")  query_flag=1 ;;
           "-csr"| "--createabc") createsr_flag=1 ;; 
           "-g" | "--getconf") getconfig_flag=1 ;;
           "-catt" | "--createandattach") createattach_flag=1 ;;
           "-att" | "--attach") attach_flag=1 ;;
           "--val1" ) callerId="$1" ;;
           "--val2" ) title="$1" ;;
           "--val3" ) urgency="$1" ;;
           "--val4" ) environment="$1" ;;
           "--val5" ) failType="$1" ;;
           "--val6" ) jobName="$1" ;;
           "--val7" ) jobType="$1" ;;
              # usage();;
              # "*" )
              # OPTIONAL="${opt#*=}";;             #take argument
              # *) echo >&2 "Invalid option: $@"; exit 1;;
            esac

            shift 
    done
```

running

```
 script.sh -c --val1 123456
```

does not work !

```
  script.sh --val1 123456  -c
```

This works !

Can you explain why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are unconditionally calling `shift` twice per iteration. This is desirable for the `--valN` cases but not for the options which do not take a following argument. You could take the general case and nest within that to reduce duplication:

```
case "$opt" in
    "-c" | "--create") create_flag=1 ;;
    "--val?" )
        case "$opt" in
            "--val1" ) callerId="$1" ;;
        esac
        shift
        ;;
esac
```

or sprinkle `shift` into all the options which take an argument like:

```
case "$opt" in
    "-c" | "--create") create_flag=1 ;;
    "--val1" ) callerId="$1" ; shift ;;
esac
```

You may also find [getopts](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial) useful for parsing options in bash.

Comment: Thanks,Used 2nd option , I just removed the final shift and added shift for all argument reads. That fixed it. Thanks for the other solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

Because your while-loop unconditionally shifts twice, even when the option doesn't take an argument. The second command line's ordering is merely getting lucky.